# ScrollView with Constraint layout

Tags: android

I have inserted a Scroll View with a inserted Constrainted Layout. However, I do not exactly know, how this scroll view is supposed to work. For testing I wanted to insert an element that is initially not visible but becomes visible when scrolling. I made the scroll view bigger than the screen and inserted it at a position in the scroll view that is initially not visible (see screenshot below).

[image: android studio with emulator]

However when I run the app in the emulator, this button is immediately visible at a position where I did not put it to (see screenshot below).

[image: android emulator]

What can I do in order to get the desired behaviour?

Here is the whole XML code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">




    '<!--Learning: The following lines define a toolbar -->'

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_left_menu_login6"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="182dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="Test This text is too"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.761" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:background="#435cb53f"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bestellen_Button"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Bestellen_Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Statistik_Button"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/Statistik_Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.057"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="465dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_ToolBar_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TestText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.421"
        tools:text="TestText" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="536dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.67"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="700dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.216"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="59dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.123"
                app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'd appreciate every kind of input. Thank you in advance for that.

Comment: In your screen shot nested scrollview have some error. solve it.

Comment: I have fixed that. But this did not cause the problem

Answer (score 3):

view on whole screen or half?If you want to scroll full screen then you need to put the scroll view out the parent layout then it will start to work

```
  <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">




    '<!--Learning: The following lines define a toolbar -->'

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_left_menu_login6"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="182dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="Test This text is too"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.761" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:background="#435cb53f"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bestellen_Button"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="BEST"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Statistik_Button"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Statistik"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.057"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="465dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_ToolBar_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TestText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.421"
        tools:text="TestText" />



        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="700dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.216"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="59dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.123"
                app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer rechna. How can I put the scroll view out of the parent layout? I just copied the xml part of the scroll view out of the parent layout (constraint layout) but afterwards it was not visible at all. In fact, I would like to have a full screen and I would like to arrange the objects in the ScrollView with a constraint layout.

Comment: @VanessaF I edited the answer you can check it and it's working, if you looking for the same

Comment: Thanks a lot rachna for you help.

Comment: I have a further question regarding this. I do not really understand why I have to use two Constraint Layouts within the scroll view. If I delete one of them, then the ability to scroll is also eliminated. But I don't understand why. Normally it should also work with only one Constrained Layout and a Scroll View. The Scroll View should just consist of the one constrained Layout in which you can put in the different elements

Comment: yes ,within  one Constraint layout it can possible,but when your layout is larger than your screen, it will also not scroll in this also becuase your layout isn't large

Comment: Thaks for your answer rachna. Still I do not understand why I need two constrained layouts. One should be enough, but it does not work with one

Comment: Hi, it's me again. I would like to have a toolbar that is permanetly visible at the top of the screen even if you scroll down. How can I do that?

Comment: The answer is not really what I want. I would like to have the Constrained Layout at the top, such that I can add a permanent toolbar at the top and at the bottom of the screen and within these layouts there should be a ScrollView. And if it is possible, the scroll view should be usable with a Constrained Layout such that I can just use the layout editor of Android studio to put the elements into their position.

Comment: Can nobody help. I really tried a lot without success

Comment: How can I have fixed toolbars within the Scroll View?

Comment: why you want to use only Constraint layout?

Comment: i have done these things without using constrint layout and which is working perfect

Comment: Thanks Rachna for your comments. I want to use the Constrained Layout because the other Layout types (like linear layout) seem to be quite difficult for a beginner like me. I think Constrained Layout is the easiest because you can just use Android Studio and designe the layout in the editor

Comment: hey linear layout and the relative layout is the simple and the easy layout for the beginner you should learn or read difference between relative, frame,linear,absolute,coordinate and constraint layout then you will understand which layout will be best for your UI

Comment: Thanks rachna for your answer. Is it not possible to put a constrained layout into a ScrollView such that you have fixed toolbars? In my Andorid studio I do not have relative layout and linear layout can get really complicated because you have to use nested groups.

Comment: By the way, I am pretty sure that Constrained Layout is better and easier for me for normal Activies. Also here you can read that Constrained Layout can be used in a very simple way with the Layout Editor of Android Studio by drag-and-dropping: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout. The problem just arises, when trying to combined a Scroll View with it. Do you know any website where I can learn how to combine them?

Comment: Does anybody know a good tutorial for combining a ScrollView with a Constrained Layout? As posted before, the use of a "normal" Constrained Layout is quite simple and I do not have any problems with that. Things become extremely challenging for me when combining it with a Scroll View

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your ScrollView is not constrained properly to its parent. Check that out.

Comment: If I constrainted it to the parents I can't make the view bigger than the actual layout. The aim of a ScrollView however is, that I have more items in it than I can put into the actual layout such that the user can scroll down.

Comment: Can nobody help? This is more a general question of how to use the ScrollView. I would be really thankful.

Comment: Has nobody had experience with the class ScrollView or can you just not figure out what is going wrong in my example. Again, I would really appreciate your help because I have been trying to solve this issue without success.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide source code for your xml and also details about functionality?

Comment: I posted the whole xml code. About the functionality there is not that much to say. As I am a beginner, I only want to try things out. In this case I would like to test a scroll view. I many applications the normal layout is not big enough for all the content. I would allow the user to scroll down in order to see furher content.

Comment: Hi it's me again. I just wanted to ask, whether there is a good tutorial on combining a ScrollView with a Constrained Layout? I have watched many videos and tutorials about Constrained Layout and I understand how it works. Nonetheless, combining this with a ScrollView makes thing really difficult and confusing for me. Does anyone know a good tutorial or have some tipps. I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for this kind of screen[image: in this image relative layout is used and in the blank area is scrollable where table will be scroll]

Comment: Thanks Rachna for your answer. I would like to have a view where I can scroll. So I need a ScrollView. At the top and at the bottom there should be a fixed Toolbar. I think in your example you can not scroll.

Comment: I have used scroll in this

Comment: Thanks rachna for your comment: Which layout did you use inside the scroll View and outside the Scroll View?

Comment: Relative layout and Linear layout you can you any

Comment: Thanks rachna for your comment. So outside there is a relative layout and inside there is a linear layout? What is the difference between a relative and a constrained layout?